# window.send_to_editor throws unterminated string literal error when adding image with multi line description

Tags: javascript, media

I am using `media-upload.php?type=image&tab=library` script to add an image to a post with a description that contains html. This php script uses the javascript function `window.send_to_editor` to send the html to the page. This allows you to insert image html into a post.

The problem is, if you try to add an image with a description that has text broken up on multiple lines(html) you will get a `unterminated string literal` error from javascript b/c the string is not converted correctly before it is used.

Is there anyway around this?

Comment: you have to use the image_send_to_editor filter to filter the string before it arrives at the window.send_to_editor javascript function.

    add_filter('image_send_to_editor', 'my_image_send_to_editor', 10, 2);
    
    function my_image_send_to_editor($html, $id) {
       $description = str_replace("\r\n",' ', $description);
    }

Comment: Can you post your answer as an __answer__ and mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1):

From comments:

> You have to use the image_send_to_editor filter to filter the string before it arrives at the window.send_to_editor javascript function.

```
add_filter('image_send_to_editor', 'my_image_send_to_editor', 10, 2); 
function my_image_send_to_editor($html, $id) 
{ 
    $description = str_replace("\r\n",' ', $description); 
}
```